# Screenshot to any screen (Android Root, like Screenshot UX)

Tags: android, screenshot

I have my code all done, and I've tryed severall codes to take screenshots, but none of them works for me. Some just work on my activity layout, but I don't want that, I wat to take a screenshot to any screen in my device, like in Screenshot UX `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.shotuxtrial`, and I know that this only can be done with root access. I've heard about methods like `screencap` and `dev/graphics/fb0`, but I know that the "`screencap`" method don't work in my device (2.3.7), and i don't still quite get it about how to use the `dev/graphics/fb0` method... I still tryed librarys methods but not in a sucessfull way. Hope someone can help me to get my screenshot code. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Access to framebuffers is restricted by permissions.
If you run

```
$ ls -l /dev/graphics
```

you can verify that

```
crw-rw---- root     graphics  29,   0 2013-07-10 10:21 fb0
crw-rw---- root     graphics  29,   1 2013-07-10 10:21 fb1
crw-rw---- root     graphics  29,   2 2013-07-10 10:21 fb2
crw-rw---- root     graphics  29,   3 2013-07-10 10:21 fb3
crw-rw---- root     graphics  29,   4 2013-07-10 10:21 fb4
```

access (`rw`) is only granted to `root:graphics`, so you'll have to root your device.

Comment: I have my device rooted, but still, can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: Then you can change these files permissions and turn them world readable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code for taking a screen shot via a shell command on rooted device 'fileDestination' is the path for the location at which you want your screenshot file to be saved.

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

    OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
    os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + fileDestination).getBytes("ASCII"));
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG,LOG_LABEL+" IOException e:: SCREENSHOT FAILED");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.d(TAG,LOG_LABEL+"InterruptedException e:: SCREENSHOT FAILED");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```